# how do i get accented characters to display in Fusion Charts graphs?

Tags: php, xml, flash, character-encoding, fusioncharts

im using fusion charts to map data. the labels for the data are country names which we localise into languages that have accents, for ex österreich being german for austria.

the data and labels are set in an xml file. for some graphs the accents show by using the decimal equivalent, so &#246; shows an ö. on other graphs the decimal, entity, hex or original character dont show the correct character on the site and im unable to identify why it works in one file and not the other. the xml file is static so php functions are not available.

how can i get these characters to show appear correctly when they are pulled from the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the XML with PHP? Make sure to send UTF-8 headers. Fusion Charts does support UTF-8. Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I thought of that too but the xml is static and the file is encoded in UTF-8. with or without BOM makes no difference.

Comment: Perhaps try LiveHTTPHeaders plugin (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) and load the XML doc to ensure the web server isn't reporting a different character encoding. That's all I can think of!

Comment: some more info: when trying to print out "Österreich" in one of their flash graphs, using the entity "&Ouml;" does NOT work. when i load the xml straight in firefox, the browser tells me "XML Parsing Error: undefined entity". When I use the decimal equivalent "&#214;" instead, firefox reports no errors when reading the xml and the character appears correctly in *some* of their graphs, but not in others. the first Ö character is just left out.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly embed the UTF-8 characters (instead of the encoded values).

For this you would need to speficically add UTf-8 BOM stamp to the XML file.

There is more information on this in FusionCharts's Documentation : Please check:

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?advanced/special-chars/SpChar.html